# listener and observer on size of NSMutableArray

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

Is it possible to do something like this in objective-C, say that my array count is X, then I want it to trigger the function Y when that happens? So a listener to the NSArray count?

Comment: This is very similar to your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/302365/observing-an-nsmutablearray-for-insertion-removal.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you could create an observer that listens for a change on an array. When its triggered you could check the size of the array and call method Y if the condition is met.

Answer (score -2):

You could write a protocol (e.g. call it `MutableArrayDelegate`), then extend `NSMutableArray` (be sure to call `[super ...]` appropriately) calling delegate methods when certain events take place.

For example, to add a listener each time an object is added:

```
@protocol MutableArrayDelegate
- (void)mutableArrayDidAddObject:(NSMutableArray *)mutableArray;
@end

@interface ObservableMutableArray : NSMutableArray
@property (nonatomic, assign) id<MutableArrayDelegate> delegate;
@end

@implementation ObservableMutableArray
@synthesize delegate;

- (void)addObject:(id)anObject
{
     [super addObject:anObject];
     [delegate mutableArrayDidAddObject:self];
}
@end
```

You can then listen for events by assigning a delegate to your subclass and implementing the protocol.

Comment: If you subclass `NSArray` you "must override the primitive instance methods `count` and `objectAtIndex:`" For `NSMutableArray` you'll need to override even more methods: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSMutableArray

Comment: My bad. Sounds like you'll be calling `[super ...]` a lot... Really deserves the downvote? Still provides the desired result.

Comment: No, calling `super` is not enough, you need to implement it yourself. `NSArray` and `NSMutableArray` are class clusters, they do not implement anything themselves. When you create an array you are getting a private subclass back, usually this isn't important to usage and just an implementation detail, but it means that when subclassing you need to implement the primitive instance methods and the storage yourself, you cannot rely on `super`.