# A general understanding of Deep Copy of NSMutableArray

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa, ipad

I have one scenario here, and maybe someone could enlighten me at this corner stone. I have a singleton where initially my json is getting parsed, and I am loading the contents from there to my Data Model.

Now lets say I deep copy from singleton to my data model, is there anyway to transverse the information back to the singleton when information changes in my data model? At current I am doing some brute forcing to update my data model and singleton objects to keep consistency, but I simple think this is a bad approach.

There would be some better way to reverse deep copy somehow, but just trying to see my options here.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably look into KVO, i.e. the mechanism that enables bindings or CoreData.

Definitely check the Apple docs - but for a quick starter have a look at 
[Observing an NSMutableArray for insertion/removal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/302365/observing-an-nsmutablearray-for-insertion-removal)

Comment: Thanks @Jay. Currently I have two NSMutableArray's one with All contents, and one with All contents - x. I want to determine what is x here and set some value in nsmutablearray of each x. Do you think there is a way to compare two NSMutableArray and set the value of something that doesn't matches somehow? Thanks