# Observing Changes to a mutable array using KVO vs. NSNotificationCenter

Tags: ios, model-view-controller, delegates, key-value-observing, nsnotificationcenter

In my model I have an array of objects called events. I would like my controller to be notified whenever a new object is added to events.

I thought that a good way to do this would be use the KVO pattern to get notified when the events changes (from a new object being added)

```
// AppDelegate
// events is a NSMutableArray @property/@synthesize etc...

[appDelagate addObserver:self
               forKeyPath:@"events"
                  options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew
                  context:NULL];
```

But the *observeValueForKeyPath* method wasn't being called and I discovered that Arrays are not KVO compliant :-(

One option is to manually trigger the method by calling *willChangeValueForKey* for the keyPath

```
// ViewController
[self willChangeValueForKey:@"events"];
[self.events addObject:event];
[self didChangeValueForKey:@"events"];
```

But this feels heavy since I should probably also keep track of the before and after state of my events array so that it can be accessed from the *observeValueForKeyPath* method.

One approach could be to use a standard array (instead of mutable) and create/set a new instance of events each time I want to add an new object, or I could make a separate property that keeps track of how many items are in the mutable array (I wish you could observe @"events.count" ).

Another option would be to use NSNotificationCenter. I've also read some answers that suggest using blocks (but I have no idea where to start on that).

Finally, could I keep an instance of my controller in my delegate and just send a relevant message?

```
// Delegate
[myController eventsDidChange];
```

Is it odd to keep a reference to a controller from a delegate?

I'm struggling to understand how to choose which is the best approach to use, so any advice on performance, future code flexibility and best practices is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You should not make direct public properties for mutable collections to avoid them mutating without your knowledge. `NSArray` is not key-value observable itself, but your one-to-many *property* `@"events"` is. Here's how to observe it:

First, declare a public property for an immutable collection:

```
@interface Model
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSArray *events;
@end
```

Then in your implementation back it with a mutable ivar:

```
@interface Model ()
{
    NSMutableArray *_events;
}
@end
```

and override the getter and setter:

```
@implementation Model

@synthesize events = _events;

- (NSArray *)events
{
    return [_events copy];
}

- (void)setEvents:(NSArray *)events
{
    if ([_events isEqualToArray:events] == NO)
    {
        _events = [events mutableCopy];
    }
}

@end
```

If other objects need to add events to your model, they can obtain a mutable proxy object by calling `-[Model mutableArrayValueForKey:@"events"]`.

```
NSMutableArray *events = [modelInstance mutableArrayValueForKey:@"events"];
[events addObject:newEvent];
```

This will trigger KVO notifications by setting the property with a new collection each time. For better performance and more granular control, implement the rest of the [array accessors](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/AccessorConventions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002174-178830-BAJEDEFB).

See also: [Observing an NSMutableArray for insertion/removal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/302365/observing-an-nsmutablearray-for-insertion-removal).

Comment: Thank you! mutableArrayValueForKey does the trick.
Do you have any tips around how you choose which pattern to use (KVO, NotificationCenter, delegate) when you want to communicate between model to controller?

Comment: I'm certainly missing something here.  Could someone please explain where setEvents would get called if someone were to add or insertObject: atIndex: an object to the backing mutable array?

Answer (score 0):

Per the [docs on accessor methods](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/AccessorConventions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002174-SW5), you should implement:

```
- (void)addEventsObject:(Event*)e
{
    [_events addObject:e];
}

- (void)removeEventsObject:(Event*)e
{
    [_events removeObject:e];
}
```

Then KVO will fire the notifications when these are called.