# KVO on removeAllObjects Triggers NSKeyValueChangeRemoval for each Item Separately

Tags: ios, key-value-observing, kvc

I'm watching an `NSArray` `property` with `KVO`. I've implemented `KVC` like in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10436587/354018) and I also implemented most of the `KVC` array accessors. To mutate it, I use `mutableArrayValueForKey`. It works fine, except to 2 issues:

1. When I call `removeAllObjects`, I get a `NSKeyValueChangeRemoval` change **for each single removed item**. I'd like to receive only one `NSKeyValueChangeRemoval` notification with all removed indexes in it.
2. Similarly when I call `addObjectsFromArray:`, I get `NSKeyValueChangeInsertion` for each single added item. I'd like to receive only one `NSKeyValueChangeInsertion` notification with all added indexes in it.

---

Notice that I *do* have implemented the KVC methods `remove<Key>ItemsAtIndexes:` and `insert<Key>Items:atIndexes:`. They are *not* called though.

I use the following workarounds:

```
- (void)removeAllObjectsWorkaroundFromArray:(NSMutableArray *)modelArray {
    NSRange indexRange;
    indexRange.length = modelArray.count;
    indexRange.location = 0;
    NSIndexSet *indexSet = [NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:indexRange];
    [modelArray removeObjectsAtIndexes:indexSet];
}

- (void)addObjectsFromArrayWorkaroundWithArray:(NSMutableArray *)modelArray arrayToAdd:(NSArray *)arrayToAdd {
    NSRange indexRange;
    indexRange.length = arrayToAdd.count;
    indexRange.location = modelArray.count;
    NSIndexSet *indexSet = [[NSIndexSet alloc] initWithIndexesInRange:indexRange];
    [modelArray insertObjects:arrayToAdd atIndexes:indexSet];
}
```

**Is there a way to directly use `removeAllObjects` and `addObjectsFromArray:` without the need for the above workarounds?**

Comment: Typo in last line of code?

Comment: Yepp, thanks. Corrected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I am sure you are aware one cannot observe the array itself, just attributes of it. So I think your workaround is unavoidable.

That being said - I really like the way you solved this!

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more on why you think it's unavoidable? I guess the problem stems from the implementation of the methods `removeAllObjects` and `addObjectsFromArray:` which add/remove items one-by-one. To be sure I asked the question, maybe I overlooked something. When the workaround is unavoidable, I'd make the workaround methods category-methods on `NSArray`.

Comment: As I said, the objects of the array are observed, not the array itself. That explains the unavoidable. Category seems a good way to go.