# Can a UIViewController written in Swift act as an Observer for an Object written in ObjC

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, key-value-observing

I am trying to observe value changes of an `NSMutableArray` in an object written in ObjectiveC. The observer however is an `UIViewController` written in Swift.
I'm not able to get the KVO notifications. These are my changes:

```
@interface Record : BaseObject
@property (nonatomic) NSMutableArray *commentsArray;


-(NSUInteger) countOfCommentsArray {
    return _commentsArray.count;
}
-(id) objectInCommentsArrayAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index {
    return [_commentsArray objectAtIndex:index];
}
-(void) insertObject:(Comment *)comment inCommentsAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index {
    [_commentsArray insertObject:comment atIndex:index];
}

-(void) insertComments:(NSArray *)array atIndexes:(NSIndexSet*)indexes {
    [_commentsArray insertObjects:array atIndexes:indexes];
}

-(void) removeCommentsAtIndexes:(NSIndexSet *)indexes {
    [_commentsArray removeObjectsAtIndexes:indexes];
}

-(void) removeObjectFromCommentsAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index {
    [_commentsArray removeObjectAtIndex:index];
}
-(void) replaceObjectInCommentsAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index withObject:(id)object {
    [_commentsArray replaceObjectAtIndex:index withObject:object];
}
```

The BaseObject derives from `NSObject`.

In my Observer class which is a Viewcontroller, and written in Swift I have the following.

In one of setup methods.

```
  myInspectionRecord?.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "commentsArray", options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions.New, context: nil);
```

And I have the method overrriden.

```
  override func observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath: String?, ofObject object: AnyObject?, change: [String : AnyObject]?, context: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) {
        print("Value Changed");
    }
```

But somehow when I add a new object to the array using the API itself, the `observeValue` method doesnt seem to be triggered.
Any pointers on what I might be missing here?
Or doesn't KVO work between Swift and Objective C files?

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24092285/is-key-value-observation-kvo-available-in-swift

Comment: Is `myInspectionRecord` actually pointing to the final object you want to observe by the time that code is run? In other words: put a breakpoint on the `addObserver` line and see whether `myInspectionRecord` is `nil`. If you're assigning to that variable, make sure to always un-register and re-register before setting it.

Comment: BTW, since your Swift class derives from `UIViewController` (and thus from `NSObject`), KVO works just fine with it.

Comment: Yes. I checked that. `myInspectionRecord` is not nil. I am registering and unregistering everytime the variable is being set either. I'm wondering if I have missed any steps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've implemented the to-many key-value *coding* (!) methods according to [Apple's KVC guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/AccessorConventions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002174-178830-BAJEDEFB), but the method names are wrong.

Since your property is named `commentsArray`, all of the methods need to include that full name. For example, your `insertObject:inCommentsAtIndex:` should be named `insertObject:inCommentsArrayAtIndex:`.

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/304143/400056) this should then give you the KVO calls for free, but you have to actually call them: the compiler seems to recognize that it needs to inject the required KVO calls for these methods.

The problem right now with your code is, neither of your methods *alter the property* and even if the compiler does inject KVO code, it would do so for the wrong key path (`comments` instead of `commentsArray`). There are two solutions: it seems using those KVC-methods give you KVO for free but I've never used this magic, so I don't know from experience whether it will work. It should, though.

There is a "brute-force" way that you could use if you want to modify the array in a completely different method: call the [KVO methods `willChangeValueForKey:` and `didChangeValueForKey:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSKeyValueObserving_Protocol/) or even better, [`willChange:valuesAtIndexes:forKey:` and `didChange:valuesAtIndexes:forKey:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSKeyValueObserving_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/willChange:valuesAtIndexes:forKey:) yourself, like this:

```
[self willChangeValueForKey:NSStringFromSelector(@selector(commentsArray))];
// Modify commentsArray
[self didChangeValueForKey:NSStringFromSelector(@selector(commentsArray))];

// or better, for an insertion:

NSIndexSet *set = [NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:someIndex];
NSString *key = NSStringFromSelector(@selector(commentsArray));
[self willChange:NSKeyValueChangeInsertion valuesAtIndexes:set forKey:key];
[_commentsArray insertObject:someObject atIndex:someIndex];
[self didChange:NSKeyValueChangeInsertion valuesAtIndexes:set forKey:key];
```

(I like to use `NSStringFromSelector(@selector(commentsArray))` instead of `@"commentsArray"` since the compiler then knows it's a selector and refactoring will then warn you when you rename the property, for example.)

Comment: The property itself doesn't have to change -- as long as the array is changed via those specifically named methods, you'll get change notifications for inserts / deletes on that array.  You're right about the naming though, that's the main problem.  Nice spot.  I think if the OP fixes them to be like `insertObject:inCommentsArrayAtIndex:` then the KVO notifications will work.

Comment: Thanks. That helped. The variable was named `comments` earlier. Guess thats the reason Xcode suggested the method. Fixed the method names and it worked.